# How to do Eclipse + Zend (Magento) Debugging on Local Machine?

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, magento, zend-studio

I'm trying to figure out how to do debugging on Zend (more specifically Magento) code using Eclipse.

This is the workflow I'd like:

1. Set breakpoints in Eclipse.
2. Open up Firefox or Chrome, pull up the site in the browser
3. When code hits the breakpoint, Eclipse halts execution, letting me look trace everything.

Right now, I debug the application using Debug As inside Eclipse, it all works great, but I don't want to use the browser in Eclipse, I want to be able to use any browser on my desktop.

Here is my setup:

Ubuntu 10.04.1

/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/ZendDebugger.so
zend_debugger.allow_hosts=127.0.0.1/32,127.0.1.1/32,192.168.15.233
zend_debugger.expose_remotely=always
zend_debugger.httpd_uid="33"
```

uid 33 being www-data.

Pulling up a PHP test file in the browser which just has phpinfo() spits out:

```
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Zend Debugger v5.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2010, by Zend Technologies
```

I think I do notice is when I do 'php -m' at the command line, there is nothing listed under [Zend Modules].

I guess the process that I'm pulling up in Firefox is not the same processes that Eclipse Debug is connecting to. How do I get them to talk to each other?

I would like to do this without install Zend studio or Zend servers since the company won't pay for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can define available web browers within eclipse prefences (just type browser in the preferences search filter). Select "use external web browser", and choose the browser you want and you're done.
Then under php > debug > workbench option, you may uncheck "open php debug views"